# reading binary files with R

Tags: c#, r

I have to translate a project from c# to R. In this c# project i have to handle binary files.
I have three problems:

1.I am having some issues to convert this code:

```
//c#     
//this work fine
using (BinaryReader rb = new BinaryReader(archive.Entries[0].Open())){
   a = rb.ReadInt32();
   b = rb.ReadInt32();
   c = rb.ReadDouble();
}

#R
#this work, but it reads different values
#I tried to change the size in ReadBin, but it's the same story. The working diretory is the right one
to.read <- "myBinaryFile.tmp"
line1<-c(readBin(to.read,"integer",2), 
         readBin(to.read,"double",1))
```

2. How can I read float (in c# i have `rb.ReadSingle()`) in R?
3. Is there in R a function to memorize the position that you have arrived when you are reading a binary file? So next time you will read it again, you could skip what you have already read (as in c# with `BinaryReader`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions directly:

1. *I am having some issues to convert this code...*

   What is the problem here? Your code block contains the comment "but it's the same story", but what is the story? You haven't explained anything here. If your problem is with the double, you should try setting `readBin(..., size = 8)`. In your case, your code would read `line1 <- c(readBin(to.read,"integer", 2), readBin(to.read, "double", 1, 8))`.
2. *How can I read float (in c# i have rb.ReadSingle()) in R?*

   Floats are 4 bytes in size in this case (I would presume), so set `size = 4` in `readBin()`.
3. Is there in R a function to memorize the position that you have arrived when you are reading a binary file? So next time you will read it again, you could skip what you have already read (as in c# with `BinaryReader`)

   As far as I know there is nothing available (more knowledgeable people are welcome to add their inputs). You could, however, easily write a wrapper script for `readBin()` that does this for you. For instance, you could specify how many bytes you want to discard (i.e., this can correspond to `n` bytes that you have already read into R), and read in that many bytes via a dummy `readBin()` like so `readBin(con = yourinput, what = "raw", n = n)`, where the integer `n` would indicate the number of bytes you wish to throw away. Thereafter, you could have your wrapper script go read succeeding bytes into a variable of your choice.